# Issue with route and post request in my angular.js/express/node app

Tags: angularjs, express, post, routes

Here's my angular controller with my post request:

```
$http.post('/formDevis', $scope.formData).then(function(response) {
  if (response.data) {
    $('#successModal').modal();
    console.log(response);
  }
}, function(response) {
  $('#errorModal').modal();
});
```

Here's my file 'server.js' with my express config:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/formDevis', function(req, res) {
  const devis = req.body;
  res.send('it work');
});
```

Ok, so if i do this, i have a response and my form is posted.
The problem is with my severals url in my app. I can't access my url, if i type it directly in a browser. Example: if i type 'my.com/users', it throw me an error.

I have a file 'routes.js' with all my route using uiRouter. And I think ,may be I have to connect that file with my express config ?

I try to add this:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

And then, all my routes worked, and I can access to them directly in the browser. But on the other hand, my post request doesn't work anymore.
In response, it send me my index.html file.

I try severals things, and none of them worked. I'm new to express, so sorry if my question is dumb. May be I missed something obvious !
Thank for your help

Comment: You can't send post request from the browser because browser sends to get the request to a server. for accessing static file use express.static.
`app.use('/', express.static('public'))`

Comment: If you want to make it easier for people to help, formulate a better question.  The question is not clear for me :)

Comment: @thomann061 sorry if i'm not clear. With my actual code, I can send my form to an email address with express(and nodemailer), but I have an issue with my route. If I type directly my url in the browser like 'myapp.com/user' , i can't get my page. I add the lines of code I noted at the bottom of my post, and then, my url work fine, but i break my post request for my form. (and sorry for my english! I hope it's more clear, I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

This will serve up the the public directory as static files (no virtual roots declared):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

So if you have the following folder structure `public/index.html`, you could visit the page like this - `localhost:3000/index.html`

Same thing for `public/css/styles.css`, you could access that file like this - `localhost:3000/css/styles.css`

Now that is great, but what if you want to change the route?

**Define a virtual root for a static file**:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.use('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/users.html');
});
```

Source: [Serving static files in express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help @thomann061, but it's doesn't work for me. I think my question wasn't clear enough in the first place.

I have a file 'routes.js' with all my route using uiRouter. And for one view in my app, I have multiples files html (one for the navbar, several for the main content, one for the footer ...).

```
 routing.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider) => {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      'nav@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/nav.html',
        controller: 'NavController'
      },
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/content/acceuil/acceuil.html',
        controller: 'TranslateController'
      },
      'clients@home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/content/acceuil/clients.html',
        controller: 'ClientsController'
      },
      'top-footer@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/footer/top-footer.html'
      },
      'footer@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/footer/footer.html'
      }
    }
  }).state('devis', {
    url: '/devis',
    views: {
      'nav@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/nav.html',
        controller: 'NavController'
      },
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/content/devis/devis.html',
        controller: 'DevisController'
      },
      'cgv@devis': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/content/devis/cgv.html'
      },
      'success@devis': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/content/devis/success.html'
      },
      'error@devis': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/content/devis/error.html'
      },
      'top-footer@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/footer/top-footer.html'
      },
      'footer@': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/footer/footer.html'
      }
    }
    });
```

Then , I add this line of code in my 'server.js':

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.post('/formDevis', function(req, res) {
  const devis = req.body;
  res.send('it work');
});
```

Like this, it worked for me, all my routes, and my post request.